# Stack 2 fixed divs after scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

I am trying to have two menus that start at the top and bottom of the home page. Then, as you scroll, the top menu stays fixed at the top but the bottom menu follows the bottom of that div until it reaches just below the top menu. Then the two scroll together throughout the rest of the page.

[image: How I want menu to look]

Currently, I am adding a class to the bottom menu when it reaches the top of the page. That class adds top: 60px to the position: fixed property to account for the top fixed menu. I was hoping there was a way to make the two recognize each other and stack vertically accordingly? But also still have the bottom menu appear at the bottom of my image slider. This will fix a lot of the responsive issues I have.

The jquery I am using to add the class is:

```
var menu = $('#bottom-header');
var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

function scroll () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
    menu.addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    menu.removeClass('sticky');
  }  
}
document.onscroll = scroll;
```

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/bwee4x2h/

Comment: Can you create fiddle for your issue? So, we can understand it better.

Comment: This is essentially how I have things set up currently: https://jsfiddle.net/bwee4x2h/

Comment: You want the top menu, image slider and bottom menu to always stack on each other?? Do I understand that correctly? Then you could place them all fixed...?

Comment: I want them to function the way they do in the js fiddle but just a more elegant solution. Right now the bottom menu scrolls past the top menu before the sticky class is added.